# Active verses passive coordinate change

Tags: examples-counterexamples, coordinate-systems

**True story:**

When I left for the summer my office number was 3291. However, when I returned this week I found my office had number 3183.

To be clear, relative to the fixed frame of reference as set by the rigid structure of the building in which my office is found, my office is the same physical location. Furthermore, all the room numbers were changed throughout the building.

So, my question,

> **Question:** is the change of coordinates I experienced this summer an example of **active** or **passive** coordinate change.

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your office is the same, there was no physical change, just a change of basis, hence the change of coordinate you experienced was a **passive** coordinate change.